# Dark Confidant and split cards

Tags: magic-the-gathering

On my upkeep controlling a [Dark Confidant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Confidant) I trigger revealing a card and losing life to it's cmc cost. What happens if I have a split card with 2 identifiable spells? Do I get to choose which one I would prefer to lose my life on?

Comment: Please link to cards (by using `[mtg:Card Name]`).

Comment: Don't use split cards with the new dark confidant vampire!

Comment: @wesdfgfgd Why not? Blood Scrivener only makes you lose 1 life, not life equal to the CMC. It would be  abetter option that Dark Confidant.

Comment: @SocioMatt Blood Scrivener is the Dark Confidant **Zombie**.  Wes is talking about  Duskmantle Seer.

Comment: @AlexP Good call. It was the word "new" that threw me off.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it's somewhere other than on the stack or if it's fused, a split card's CMC is the sum of each half's CMC.

> 708.4. In every zone except the stack, the characteristics of a split card are those of its two halves combined. This is a change from previous rules.
>
> 708.4b The mana cost of a split card is the combined mana costs of its two halves. A split card’s colors and converted mana cost are determined from its combined mana cost.
>
> ***Example:** Assault/Battery’s mana cost is {3}{R}{G}. It’s a red and green card with a converted mana cost of 5.  If you cast Assault, the resulting spell is a red spell with a converted mana cost of 1.*

708.4b is rather poorly worded. As the example shows, the mana cost and converted mana cost of a split card is only the combined mana costs or converted mana costs of its two halves *when it's not on the stack or when it's fused*.

Answer (score 8):

With the latest update to the [comprehensive rules (June 5, 2017)](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/MagicCompRules_20170605.pdf), the converted mana cost of split card is the **sum of both halves**.  This happens to align with the previous "apply both answers" approach previously, but now split cards return a single answer instead of having to deal with "halves" of cards. From the rules:

> 708.4. In every zone except the stack, the characteristics of a split card are those of its two halves combined. This is a change from previous rules.

Specifically regarding CMC (emphasis mine):

> 708.4b **The mana cost of a split card is the combined mana costs of its two halves.** A split card’s colors and converted mana cost are determined from its combined mana cost.
>
> Example: Assault/Battery’s mana cost is {3}{R}{G}. It’s a red and green card with a converted mana cost of 5. If you cast Assault, the resulting spell is a red spell with a converted mana cost of 1.